# Not able to display material ui snackbar in center

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material ui snackbar which i need to display in middle of the screen. Below is the property which i am trying to pass to make it display center of the screen but its displaying at top of the screen.

```
  anchorOrigin={{
   vertical: "center",
   horizontal: "center"
  }}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/snackbar-background-color-f37po is the example showcasing the issue. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make it vertically align center. We can use `sx` prop with `height: 100%` on Snackbar component. Tested in MuiV5 and working fine.

```
<Snackbar
   sx={{ height: "100%" }}
   anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "center"
   }}
   ...
   ...
/>
```

Comment: @Gangadhar Gandi I need to change vertical to "top" to make it work as it only accepts "top" or "bottom"

Comment: This creates a bug where the snackbar jumps some pixels once loaded. feels wierd once noticed. setting height : '100vh' doesnt work.

Comment: This solution has the drawback that the click-away listener doesn't work properly if you click above or below the snack bar message. It's because the message now spans from the top of the page to the bottom. Click-away works only if you click on the left or right.

Answer (score -1):

```js
<Snackbar
  open={snackbarOpen}
  autoHideDuration={900} // Adjust the duration as needed
  onClose={handleSnackbarClose}
  anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
>
  <SnackbarContent
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
    message="No results found."
  />
</Snackbar>
```

Comment: Please explain the posted code.