# How to make Material-UI Snackbar appear in center by overriding "VERTICAL"-field of "anchroOriginal"-prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, toast, snackbar

Good day, good people!
I want the Material-UI Snackbar component on some pages of my project to pop up in the center of the screen vertically. By default, the Material-UI allows the Snackbar to be aligned to the top or bottom of the screen.
Currently, to achieve this behavior I set height 100% manually in "sx", as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59954591/20126945). In order to use this component with its native settings, I want to implement a vertically centering Snackbar using the Material-UI features.
How can I add a custom value "center" to the "vertical"-field of the anchorOrigin property?

```js
export default function Toast() {
  const toast = useSelector((state) => state.toast);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClose = (_, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    dispatch(toggleToast({ open: false }));
  };

  return (
    <Snackbar
      sx={{ height: toast.height }}//want to get rid of this property
      open={true}
      anchorOrigin={toast.position ? toast.position : { vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
      autoHideDuration={toast.duration === undefined ? 4500 : toast.duration}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <Alert variant="filled" severity={toast.severity}>
        {toast.message}
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
}
```

"toggleToast"-action sets "open"-property of Snackbar as "true" and passes props to the Snackbar.

```js
dispatch(
  toggleToast({
    message: "Saved successfully",
    severity: "success",
    position: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" },
    height: "100%"
  })
)
```